# Applying sessions in cakephp 3.2

Tags: cakephp

Im using cakephp 3.2 to build an application. Im using the bookmarks tutorial as a basis for my project.  in one of my bookmarks .ctp view files I would like to have a number of select boxes with data specific to the user loggged in. i have two tables namely users and bookmarks. My bookmarks table contains foreign key from users table user_id. 
Here's my bookmark table with the fields i would like the dropdowns. id, user_id, title, systemregistration, systemroles, country, province, metropolitan.

```
Code for my appcontroller
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /*public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    }*/

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
            ],
            //'storage' => 'Session'
            'Session'
        ]);
        // Allow the display action so our pages controller
        // continues to work.
        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }

    /*public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Bookmarks',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);
    }*/

    /**
     * Before render callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
}

//BookmarksController looks like this

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;


/**
 * Bookmarks Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\BookmarksTable $Bookmarks
 */
class BookmarksController extends AppController
{
    public function internalprotocol()
    {

        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->newEntity();

        $users = $this->Bookmarks->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'users', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);

        $bookmarks = $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks);

        $this->set(compact('bookmarks'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmarks']);        
    }
}

//my internalprotocol.ctp looks like this 

<div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $bookmarks]); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('title', ['options' => $bookmarks]); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('systemregistration', ['options' => $bookmarks]); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('systemroles', ['options' => $bookmarks]); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('country', ['options' => $bookmarks]); ?>
</div>
```

I would like to populate each of the fields with data specific to the user logged in. Could you please help!

Comment: I can't understand the question. But for session you can do this `$session=$this->request->session();` Then in `$session` You can do all the stuff like `$session->write('foo','bar');`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. If a login is successful you can access the logged in user details through the `Auth` component using `$this->Auth->user();`

If you need to add any more information to the session you can use the `Session` component like `$this->Session->write('User.AscociatedData', $AscociatedData);`

Easiest way to access this data in the view is to set authenticated user as a view variable in the controller:

```
$this->set('user',$this->Auth->user());
```

then you can accesses the users info in the view with `$user` e.g`$user->fieldName`

Not entirely sure what your asking but I hope one of my answers is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

we only need to show bookmarks for the currently logged in user.

We can do that by updating the call to paginate().Make your index() action from Controller/BookmarksController.php look like:

```
public function index()
 {
  $this->paginate = [
    'conditions' => [
        'Bookmarks.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
    ]
];
$this->set('bookmarks', $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks));
$this->set('_serialize', ['bookmarks']);
```

}

**We should also update the tags() action and the related finder method as we done for bookmarks above**

Please read the tutorial

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html#fixing-list-view-and-forms